# partial derivative chain rule

Tags: calculus

$$
f(x,g(x),t) \\ \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\ \\
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \\ \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial g}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=0
$$
What's wrong with it?

Comment: First, it should be $\frac{dg}{dx}$ as $g$ only relies on one variable, $x$.

Secondly, you actually took the total derivative of $f$, not the partial, i.e.

\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \\
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \cdot \frac{dg}{dx}
\end{align}

as $t$ doesn't depend on $x$

Comment: what's $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$in this case? Thanks.

Comment: The partial derivative of the function $f$ with respect to $x$.

Comment: @Mattos That is not a "total derivative" inasmuch as $f$ depends on $x$ and $t$.  The issues is one of notational pitfall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is one of notational pitfall. We can circumvent this through a more generous use of letters.  To that end, we let $f(x,y,t)$ be a given function of three variables.  Then, for $y=g(x)$, we can write $u(x,t)=f(x,g(x),t)$ and use the chain rule to show

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\\\\
&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dg}{dx}
\end{align}$$

That is,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dg}{dx}}$$

We can alternatively use a numerical subscript notation to resolve notational problems.  Here, we write the partial derivatives of a function $f(x,y,z)$ as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=f_1(x,y,z)\\\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=f_2(x,y,z)\\\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=f_3(x,y,z)
\end{align}$$

Then, we have for $u=f(x,g(x),t)$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=f_1(x,g(x),t)+f_2(x,g(x),t)\frac{dg}{dx}}$$